# Set a global variable using top level domain in Sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

We're developing a website using Sveltekit which will be hosted on two different top level domains for two different countries and are looking for a way to read the domain and then set a 'country' parameter in our requests to our API.

Stores were my first thought, but don't seem to be an option as they are not available in the load function and also because it would seem that any store data is shared across all clients on the server side.

What could be an elegant way to manage this? Environment variables are an easy fix, but we would prefer not to run two servers just to change a single variable that can be inferred from the hostname for the request.

Thanks.

Comment: One option could be to use the [internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions): `console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale)`